# C# Conditional Anonymous Object Members in Object initialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, anonymous

I building the following anonymous object:

```cs
var obj = new {
    Country = countryVal,
    City = cityVal,
    Keyword = key,
    Page = page
};
```

I want to include members in object only if its value is present.

For example if `cityVal` is null, I don't want to add City in object initialization

```cs
var obj = new {
    Country = countryVal,
    City = cityVal,  //ignore this if cityVal is null 
    Keyword = key,
    Page = page
};
```

Is this possible in C#?

Comment: What would that even mean? The object would be missing a property that the rest of your code expects. What would `obj.City` mean? Semantically undefined.

Comment: In my case I need to create an object which gets serialized into JSON (and send it using RestSharp) - no other manipulation of the object in c#. Based on conditions some of the members should be there, some not. As it is a large object, using accepted answer requires a lot of code. So this question is reasonable. Using some kind of conditional initialization would spare coding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is it possible to have a conditional field in an anonymous type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090218/is-it-possible-to-have-a-conditional-field-in-an-anonymous-type)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its not even posibble with codedom or reflection, So you can end up doing if-else if you really need this

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cityVal)) {
    var obj = new {
        Country = countryVal,
        Keyword = key,
        Page = page
    };

    // do something
    return obj;
} else {
    var obj = new {
        Country = countryVal,
        City = cityVal,
        Keyword = key,
        Page = page
    };

    //do something 
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: This works and seems like the only method for an anonymous object. But I would be against it because it adds duplication and complexity. The better way is to adjust the rest of the codebase to handle/ignore null fields.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that.

But what you could do is provide the default value (null?) of those properties.

```
var obj=  new
            {
                Country= countryVal,
                City = condition ? cityVal : null,
                Keyword = condition ? key : null,
                Page = condition ? page : null
            };
```

Comment: You cannot use conditional initializer in anonymous types

Comment: Yes, you can use a ternary operator :|

Comment: You can use the ternary operator, but it will still add the field to the object. It will have a null value though. I think this is the way to go and the code should be adjusted to handle or ignore null values.

Answer (score 5):

Well you would have if else conditions. But, if you are serilizing this as a JSON object 
with newtonsoft JSON this could help:

```
   var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Formatting.None,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                    });
```

Comment: There is no mention of JSON on this question other than in a comment from someone else.

Comment: that's why i put a "But"

Comment: actually, this is very useful. it solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You could use an ExpandoObject and a functional extension method.

```
    pubic class SomeClass

        public dynamic DomainFunction(
            object countryVal = null
          , object cityVal = null
          , object key = null
          , object page = null
        )
        {
            dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();

            cityVal?.Tee(x => obj.City = x);
            countryVal?.Tee(x => obj.Country = x);
            key?.Tee(x => obj.Keyword = x);
            page?.Tee(x => obj.Page = x);

            return obj;
        }

    }

    public static class FunctionalExtensionMethods{

        public static T Tee<T>(this T source, Action<T> action)
        {
          if (action == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof (action));
          action(source);
          return source;
        }

    }
```