# Include properties based on conditions in anonymous types

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-types

Supposing I have the following anonymous type

```
var g = records.Select(r => new
{                    
    Id = r.CardholderNo,
    TimeIn = r.ArriveTime,
    TimeOut = r.LeaveTime,
});
```

Is it possible to do something like the following:

```
var g = records.Select(r => new
{                    
    Id = r.CardholderNo,
    if (condition) 
    {
        TimeIn = r.ArriveTime;
    },
    TimeOut = r.LeaveTime,
    //many more properties that I'd like to be dependant on conditions.
});
```

How can I achieve an anonymous type based on conditions?

Comment: var g = records.Select(r => new
            {                    
                Id = r.CardholderNo,
                TimeIn = condition?r.ArriveTime:null
                TimeOut = r.LeaveTime

            });

Comment: No it is not possible. Anonymous are strongly typed. What behaviour you would expect, when `condition` would be resolved at runtime?

Comment: I think a cast would solve the issue @pwas

Comment: It would be impossible or very hard to work with such an object when you don't know what to expect from it. You had to first check if the property exists at all and then whether it has a value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is it possible to have a conditional field in an anonymous type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090218/is-it-possible-to-have-a-conditional-field-in-an-anonymous-type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly using an `if` statement, but you could do it using the ternary operator (assuming `TimeIn` is of type `DateTime`):

```
var g = records.Select(r => new
{

    Id = r.CardholderNo,
    TimeIn = condition ? r.ArriveTime : (DateTime?)null;
    TimeOut = r.LeaveTime
});
```

Note this will make the property always appear in your Annonymous Type. If this isn't the desired behavior, then you can't do it this way.

I would suggest thinking about the readability of your code and not only about *"how can i shorten these few lines so it looks neat".*

Comment: `r.ArriveTime` must be casted to nullable if it is non nullable type. Otherwise `?` operator will fail at compile time.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by using the [ternary operator: ?:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

The syntax is like this:

```
TimeIn = condition ? r.ArriveTime : (DateTime?)null // Or DateTime.Min or whatever value you want to use as default
```

### UPDATE

After thinking about your problem for a couple of minutes I came up with the following code that you should never ever use ;)

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

        bool condition = true;

        dynamic result = condition ?
            (object)new
            {
                id = 1,
                prop = dt
            }
            :
            (object)new
            {
                id = 2,
            };

        Console.WriteLine(result.id);
        if (condition) Console.WriteLine(result.prop);
    }
}
```

This code should never be used in production because of it's terrible readability and it's really error prone. However, as a learning example of what's possible with the language it's quite nice.

Comment: `r.ArriveTime` (or null) must be casted to nullable type `(DateTime?)r.ArriveTime) : null`  - otherwise expression will fail at compile time.

Comment: what he actually expects is the property 'TimeIn' should be added to the Anonymous type based on a condition. If the condition evaluates to false, he don't want to add that property to the type

Answer (score 3):

No. Anonymous types are just like any other type. It has a fixed list of properties. You can't dynamically add or remove properties.

I suggest to either set the property to `null`, like in the other answers, or use a `Dictionary` where you add the relevant properties and their values.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need an `if` (or any another statement) in your Anonymous Type creation, you can try this not-so-pretty solution:

```
var g = records.Select(r => new
{
    Id = r.CardholderNo,
    TimeIn = new Func<DateTime?, DateTime?>(x =>
            {
            if (...)
                return x;
            else
                return null;
            }).Invoke(r.ArriveTime),
    TimeOut = r.LeaveTime,
});
```

Comment: Would you really want to use code like that just to avoid an `if` statement before the creation of the object?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer - personally, I wouldn't. But it's an option.